# Excel 2016 no more fonts

Tags: excel

Good evening, I have a very boring problem and I don't know how to get out of it.

I have many excel files that I use for work, connected with various formulas, it has become practically impossible to work with, I have already tried multiple versions of Excel (2010/2013/2016) but I always have the same problems.

When I press F2 on a cell that contains a formula or double click I get the error "No More New Fonts may be Applied in this Workbook", the problem appears only in cells with formulas, even if they are stupid formulas like a trivial subtraction.

I tried to remove all cell formats but the problem persists.

Turning on the internet I saw that the problem has always existed on Excel, at least for 17 years and who had it never solved it, there was a KB from Microsoft but it doesn't exist anymore, about Auto scaling or something like that.

I can't understand how to solve it but I have to solve it because there are years of work in these worksheets.

I can also go to an empty cell, I write to it, I put a very simple formula = A1-B2 I give OK, it saves the formula and if it enters it it gives me an error again, if instead I create a formula of the type = 2-1 no problem.

Do you have any ideas to give me?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure it will help at all, but you could try clearing excess formats using the [Inquire Add-In](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42), which should already be installed, depending on your version of Excel.

Comment: it doesn't works yet

Comment: Anyone can help me?